# How do I compare variables between subclasses to create it. Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, instance, instance-variables

We suppose I get a String input, which can be "0", "brown", ".5m" or "50cm".Then I create a dog instance of `dog` class, that is child of `pet` class. But `pet` class is super class of `horse`, `pig` and `bird`.

```
public class Pet {
    public final String[] attribs;
    public void sound() {
        System.out.print(attribs[4]);
    }
}

public class Dog extends pet {
    public final String[] attribs = {"0","brown",".5m","50cm","wow"};
}

public class Bird extends pet {
    public final String[] attribs = {"1","green",".3m","30cm","hola"};
}

public class Pig extends pet {
    public final String[] attribs = {"2","pink",".7m","75cm","oing"};
}

public class Horse extends pet {
    public final String[] attribs = {"3","black","1.5m","150cm","burf"};
}

public class app {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
        String AttribInserted;
        Pet FindedPet;
        System.out.println("type an attribute of your pet")
        AttribInserted = inputs.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
            if (l.equals(dog.atbts[i])) FindedPet = new dog();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
            if (l.equals(bird.atbts[i])) FindedPet = new bird();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
            if (l.equals(horse.atbts[i])) FindedPet = new horse();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
            if (l.equals(pig.atbts[i])) FindedPet = new pig();
        System.out.print("Your pet says:");
        FindedPet.sound();
    }
}
```

Well, if I add more subclasses of pet and I add attributes for everyone, is there a way to compare between all variables of all subclasses?. For example:
`l.equals(subclass.atbts[i])`
And most if I want to use a more complex project. `subclass.atbts[i][j][k]`

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions. `l` is an identifier the documentation specifically warns against using. Type names should begin with an upper-case letter. Did you notice that `dog.atbts`, etc., won't compile? Also, you utterly neglected to put curly braces (`{`, `}`) around your `if` and loop bodies.

Comment: @LewBloch *`l` is an identifier the documentation specifically warns against using.* Do you have a source?

Comment: I am in a ladder, I begin in a language that have no conventions and I don't take a course, I read from anywhere I need and I don't know the Java naming conventions. Also this question isn't a quote of my project, it is only a coarse and general example to be easy to understand and to be more useful. I never have used this code, I didn't compiled it.

Comment: @IcaPolinesioGarLop This is not an excuse.  When you write code, it gotta be something that is understandable by others.  It maybe because someone else is also maintaining it, or you need to show it to someone else (like now).  So, learn to write code in an understandable way is actually the most fundamental skill you need to acquire.

Comment: The official docs don't excoriate `l` specifically, so I was wrong there, but it's easily confused with `1`. However the docs do recommend against one-letter variable names. The tutorial (study it) says that. The coding conventions document says "One-character variable names should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables." The JLS says, "One-character local variable or parameter names should be avoided, except for temporary and looping variables, or where a variable holds an undistinguished value of a type." And again, `l` is especially bad because it looks like a digit.

Comment: @IcaPolinesioGarLop It's _especially_ important when "in _[sic]_ a ladder" as a beginner to develop proper habits. If you get into bad habits from the beginning it's much harder to correct them later. Making excuses for bad habits is the worst habit of all, and probably the hardest to break, but the most important.

Comment: It isn't an excuse, actually I'was asking where I can read it

Answer (score 0):

How about a `Map<String, Object>` for attributes.  The key would be the name of the attribute, and the value will of course be the value of the attribute.  This Map can be a field within Pet, so that it can be used across all subclasses.

Comment: I don't know if I am not understanding but what do I need the name of attributes for? I need create an instance in base of an attribute, choose a class for create it. Well, I suppose you mean I can map the subclasses and its attributes in a variable (I use variable because I don't know if there is difference) in pet class. But map is a table with only two spaces/column, or can I expand it?

Answer (score 0):

First, please write your code in clean and readable way, and follow proper naming convention.  Class `dog` should be `Dog`, `atbts` is not even a common abbreviation of any word.  I guess you mean `attributes` ?

Second, the design is simply irrational.

Those are not "attributes" of a pet.  You may simply think it as an "alias" of pet types.  However I don't see how `50cm` can be treated as an alias of dog: A dog can be in various size, and there are other pets that may have size of 50cm.  Without such basic design consideration be catered, it is meaningless to talk about "more complex project".  I kind of suspect you have misread your homework assignment.

However, based on your original intention, the design can still be tweaked in a slightly more meaningful form:

```
// pseudo-code

class Pet {
    protected String sound;   // these are what we called ATTRIBUTE!
    protected long size;
    // some other attributes too

    public Pet(long size, String sound /*other attributes too*/) {  
        this.size = size;
        ....
    }

    void makeSound() {
        print this.sound;
    }
}

class Dog {
    long DEFAULT_SIZE = 50;
    long DEFAULT_SOUND = "woof";
    public Dog() {
        super(DEFAULT_SIZE, DEFAULT_SOUND);
    }
    public static boolean hasAlias(String input) {
        // you can think of a way to check if input is an alias by,
        // for example, having a Set<String> which contains
        // DEFAULT_SIZE, DEFAULT_SOUND, pet name, sequence etc,
        // and simply do a aliases.contains(input);
}

// in main logic
String input = readInput();

// the following piece can be further refactored by having
// a factory, and each pet type register their alias etc...
if (Dog.hasAlias(input)) {
    pet = new Dog();
} else if Cat.hasAlias(input)) {
    pet = new Cat();
}
```

---

Update:

With extra information given in the comment of this answer, here is an updated approach.

> My original intention isn't make really funtional animals classes, my
>   intention is I input something and the app knows what I am talking, if
>   I type "ate" I need the app tell me "Ate" is in past and its
>   infinitive form is "to eat". If I type read, then the app tell me
>   "Read" is in past, past participle and present and its infinitive form
>   is "to read"

First, you shouldn't represent each "word" as a separate class.  In your example, `eat` and `read` should be one instance of something, instead of separate class for them.

For which it should look like:

```
class Word {
    Collection<String> getVariations();
}

class Verb extends Word {
    private String present;
    //....

    public Verb(String present, String past, String participle, String continuous) {
        this.present = present;
        //....
    }
}
```

In your main logic (though I would make it a separate class like a `WordRepository`):

```
class WordRepository {
    private Map<String, Word> wordVariationMap = new HashMap<>();

    void registerWord(Word word) {
        for (String variation: word.getVariations()) {
            wordVariationMap.put(variation, word);
        }
    }

    void mainLogic() {
        // create words and setup the lookup map
        registerWord(new Verb("eat", "ate", "eaten", "eating"));
        registerWord(new Verb("read", "read", "read", "reading"));

        String input = readInput();
    Word word = wordVariationMap.get(input);
    if (word) {  // if found
        word.doWhatever();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My original intention isn't make really funtional animals classes, my intention is I input something and the app knows what I am talking, if I type "ate" I need the app tell me `"Ate" is in past and its infinitive form is "to eat"`. If I type read, then the app tell me `"Read" is in past, past participle and present and its infinitive form is "to read"`.

Comment: And also last code after `String input = readInput();` is exactly that I want to avoid, If I had 100 classes I need have 100 if Statement.

Comment: Be clear on what you are trying to do.  Make sure you give meaningful example so it does not distract other from your real question.  Btw, even for what you mentioned in comment, it still does not make sense to create separate class for `eat` and `read`.  Anyway, I will update my answer a bit to cater your requirement mentioned in comment

Comment: btw, I have already given an hint in my original answer, which should drive you to what you need: _the following piece can be further refactored by having a factory, and each pet type register their alias etc..._

Comment: The sense is exactly the start of the question, in the example of the pets. if I call `FindedPet.sound();`I get different results from different classes, if I have only one class with diferent instances the mothods were equals always.

Comment: But sorry for confuse you. Thanks for the attention.